# google maps in angularjs with responsive design

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

hi I'm doing a aplication with angular, well in this app I need show map and makers, but first step I need the map, now I'am having problem in this part ok, I'm very new in angular I make maps with jquery and javascript now I tried to make the same steps and nop work yet. well I thing that this part is the important. controller of map.

mapController.js

```
(function(){
angular.module('mapCtrl', [])
    .controller('MapController', function($scope) {
        function initialize() {
            var options = {
                googleApiKey: '',
                locationColumn: 'geometry',
                map_center: [-16.494898, -68.133553],
                locationScope: 'La Paz'
            };
            var self = this;
            options = options || {};
            this.googleApiKey = options.googleApiKey || "";
            this.locationColumn = options.locationColumn || "geometry";
            this.locationScope = options.locationScope || "";
            this.defaultZoom = options.defaultZoom || 13;
            this.map_centroid = new google.maps.LatLng(options.map_center[0], options.map_center[1]);

            this.myOptions = {
                zoom: this.defaultZoom,
                center: this.map_centroid,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            //$scope.map = new google.maps.Map($("#map")[0], this.myOptions);
            $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), this.myOptions);
            //this.map = new google.maps.Map($("#map")[0], this.myOptions);
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    });
```

})();

I tried with getElementById() and dont work. Now the view.
In the express framework the route is /public/app/views/index.html, the 
route.app.js is:

```
(function(){
angular.module('app.routes', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
        });
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'app/views/pages/home.html',
                controller: 'MapController',
                controllerAs: 'main'
            })
            .when('/login', {
                templateUrl: 'app/views/pages/login.html'
            })
            .when('/about', {
                templateUrl: 'app/views/pages/about.html'
            })
            .when('/users', {
                templateUrl: 'app/views/pages/users.html'
            });
        // get rid of the hash in the URL
    });
```

})();
the app.js

```
(function(){
    angular.module('myApp', [
        'ngAnimate',
        'app.routes',
        'mainCtrl',
        'userCtrl',
        'mapCtrl',
        'userService',
        'authService'
    ]);
})();
```

in the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <title>Sociedad F</title>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta content='Team of competition' name='description' />
    <meta content='FanaticCode' name='author' />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/app/controller/mainController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/app/controller/userController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/app/controller/mapController.js"></script>
    <!-- services -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/app/services/authService.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/app/services/userService.js"></script>
    <!-- main Angular app files -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/app/app.routes.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/app/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
</head>
    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MapController as main">
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the home.html

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <!--- more html code with bootstrap -->
</div>
<div id="container" >
    <div id="sidebar">
   <!--- more html code with bootstrap -->
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

Well can see that nothing is happend I tried but dont work yet some can help me please.

[image: result of the code]

Comment: Set a height and width on your map div, does it show the map after doing this?

Comment: this work,  but Why? i had a style css #map{  width: auto !important; height: 100% !important;    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); }

Comment: > Instead of using jquery and Javascript you can use angular maps. > It is easy and simple to integrate google maps in Angular app. > Below is the link: > https://angular-maps.com/